Why I can't use gen_range method from rand::Rng trait with rand_chacha::ChaChaRng
I was looking for a seedable random number generator with consistent behavior across different platforms, and I was pointed to use ChaChaRng from the rand_chacha crate.
I need to generate numbers sampled uniformly from a range, and the range is different every time, so using distributions::Uniform is not the preferred option.
ChaChaRng implements rand_core::RngCore trait, and rand_core's documentation states that for this reason, rand::Rng trait should also be available.
However, when I attempt to use it:
use rand_chacha::ChaChaRng;
use rand_chacha::rand_core::SeedableRng;
use rand::Rng;
use rand_chacha::rand_core::RngCore;

fn test(seed: u64) {
    let mut gen = ChaChaRng::seed_from_u64(seed);
    let _ = gen.gen_range(0..10);
}

I get the following compiler error:
error[E0599]: the method `gen_range` exists for struct `ChaCha20Rng`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/lib.rs:8:17
    |
8   |     let _ = gen.gen_range(0..10);
    |                 ^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `ChaCha20Rng` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: /home/.../.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/rand_chacha-0.3.1/src/chacha.rs:343:1
    |
343 | chacha_impl!(ChaCha20Core, ChaCha20Rng, 10, "ChaCha with 20 rounds", abstract20);
    | -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- doesn't satisfy `ChaCha20Rng: Rng` or `ChaCha20Rng: rand::RngCore`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `ChaCha20Rng: rand::RngCore`
            which is required by `ChaCha20Rng: Rng`

cargo tree:
project v0.1.0
├── rand v0.9.0-alpha.1
│   ├── rand_chacha v0.9.0-alpha.1
│   │   ├── ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
│   │   └── rand_core v0.9.0-alpha.1
│   │       ├── getrandom v0.2.15
│   │       │   ├── cfg-if v1.0.0
│   │       │   └── libc v0.2.155
│   │       └── zerocopy v0.8.0-alpha.6
│   ├── rand_core v0.9.0-alpha.1 (*)
│   └── zerocopy v0.8.0-alpha.6
└── rand_chacha v0.3.1
    ├── ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
    └── rand_core v0.6.4


Might be a version mismatch between rand_core used by rand and rand_chacha can you check cargo tree?

@cafce25 You are right, I changed rand version to 0.8.5 and it fixed the problem. (You can write this in an answer if you want)
